# Apex - SalesForce - Accessing a Parent object field through Junction object

Tags: orm, salesforce, apex-code, junction-table

**Hello Folks,**

I am working on customizing some functionality on the Force.com platform. I have a question for you; I am not too sure if this is possible!

**What I have?** : 2 custom objects - abc and pqr. Abc is the junction object between the Standard object Account and pqr i.e. Account is the parent of abc and then Pqr is the parent of abc. I am retrieving everything through these objects into a List of type Account (i.e. from Account object).

**What I need?** : I can access the abc object in Apex i.e. the First child of Account. Is there a possibility to access the fields of pqr through account?

**What I have tried** : Accessing the object through relationship name - Account.abc_*r[0].pqr*_r[0].FIELDNAME

But it hasnt worked. ***Could some salesforce/apex developer help me with this?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get the information you need using a subquery. The real question here is how your query is setup. Your query will need to access all levels of the data model for it to be available. If you are relying on data returned in a trigger or standard controller then I would recommend requiring the account object to get access to the additional information.

So I would expect to see something along the lines of:

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, pqr__r.Id, pqr__r.Name FROM abc__r) FROM Account];

for (Account acct : accounts) {
    string someValue = acct.abc__r[0].pqr__r.Name;
}
```

Keep in mind though that as a best practice you shouldn't access the child records the way I did above because if there are no ABC records that object will be null so as a best practice you will want to test for that ahead of time. Same goes for PQR object data.

Comment: So which part does not work? Are you getting an error or is it that the solution doesn't provide the results you are looking for. If you could help me out with some more details I would be happy to adjust my answer.

Comment: I cannot access the field using the '.' operator. If I System.Debug the list that you created in the start, it only shows the Id and the name not anything else from pqr.

I am not too sure why is this but the query runs fine in workbench - SOQL execute but when I assign the same query to a list of type account it does not return anything except the account fields.

Is there a way to create a list of type 'Multilple objects' so the list can get all the values from SOQL?

Answer (score 2):

***The answer to this question is the following:***

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, pqr__r.Id, pqr__r.Name FROM abc__r) FROM Account];

for (Account acct : accounts) {
    for(Abc__c abc : acct.abc__r)
       {
          String someValue = abc.pqr__r.Name;
       }
}
```

**Note**: Here, abc_*r is the relationship of object Abc*_c with Account. Please comment on this if you have any questions.